# Fancybox 2.0 helper options

Tags: jquery, fancybox

What are the possible options to the new "helpers" in FB 2.0?

Some of them are in the examples on the fancyapps page but maybe there are many more.

Comment: Please do not use StackOverflow to attempt to directly contact a developer.  His recommendation to use StackOverflow for support is only for if you're having trouble with your code.  Please use [his contact page](http://fancyapps.com/contact/).

Answer (score 1):

You can check its available options here: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples

Comment: The developer has informed me that he will post a detailed list of all helper options in his blog.  The list on the fancyapps page is as yet incomplete.